# strcpy copies content of an other array

Tags: c++, arrays, string, char

So I have this piece of code to convert a char array to the contents of a struct. (no, I'm not gonna argue on whether or not this is the right/most efficient way to do it)

```
void chararray_to_categorie(categorie &levarr, char** chararray)
    {


        string temp = chararray[0];
        int length = temp.length();
        temp = temp.substr(0, ((length<21)?length:20));

        strcpy(levarr.naam, temp.c_str()); //a very sloppy way to use substring on a char array. Tried memcpy and that caused the same results which is why I'm trying it this way.
        levarr.naam[20] = '\0';

        strcpy(levarr.omschrijving, chararray[1]);


        cout << endl << chararray[0] << endl << temp << endl << levarr.naam << endl << length << endl << ((length<21) ? length : 20);
        _getch();

        /*
        input:
        naam: 1234567890123456789012345678901234567890
        omschrijving: lol

        output:
        chararray[0]: 1234567890123456789012345678901234567890
        temp: 12345678901234567890
        levarr.naam: 12345678901234567890lol

        */

    }
```

as you can see in the ouput you can see that the content of the struct has 2 chararrays combined which i the problem.

Comment: Show definition of the structure.

Comment: typedef struct
{
 int ID;
 char naam[20], omschrijving[50];
}categorie;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a lot of things suboptimal in your code but the error comes down to:

```
levarr.naam[20] = '\0';
```

which should be

```
levarr.naam[19] = '\0';
```

as arrays are counted starting with 0;

Other things to fix:

- Use a save `strcpy` function that NULL-terminates the string and features a size argument, it would have guarded you against this issue.
- Don't get a substring, copy only that many characters from the original string using a safe function.

Comment: tried to remake it with strncpy since I think that's what u suggested with a "safe function" though the same still happens, that is that chararray[1] is still being copied to levarr.naam which should only contain chararray[0].  `strncpy(levarr.naam, chararray[0],20);
 levarr.naam[19] = '/0';` actually the same happens with `levarr.naam[20] = '/0';`

Comment: @Semanresu I was careful not to say `strncpy`, since that doesn't NULL-terminate strings and, btw, NULL termination is `\0` and not `/0`.

Comment: oh missed that, thx the problem is solved. Though the only downside is that this will occupy the last slot in the array, is there a workaround for this?

Comment: @Semanresu Not really, enlarging the array is the only sensible choice.